# Why child component should be wrapped with Router as its parent component

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-navigation, react-router-dom

I'm wondering why if my parent `App` component is wrapped with `<Router history={history}>`

than it's child component  `Signup` should be wrapped again like that?

When `Signup` component is without `<Router history={history}>` it will show nothing - an empty page.
Where is the sense here ?

Index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```js
return (
    <div className='App-div'>
      <Route>
        {signUpFirst ? <Redirect to='/signup' /> : <Redirect to='/home' />}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/signup'>
            <SignUp homePage={exitSignUpPage} setUserNumber={setUserID} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/home'>
            <Home userIDNumber={userID} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
```

SignUp.js

```js
 render() {
    return (
      <div className='signUp-div'>
        <Header />
       <Router history={history}>  // Without nothing will be shown on screen
        <div className='form-div'>
          <Redirect to='/signup/mobile' />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/signup/mobile' component={MobileNum} />
            <Route exact path='/signup/idnumber'>
              <IdentNumber setPersonalID={this.props.setUserNumber} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/signup/password'>
              <CreatePass />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
         </Router> 
      </div>
    );
```

Will be gald for someone who understands this.

Answer (score 1):

1. App.js

```js
import  routes  from "./Route.js";
    function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              {routes.map((prop, key) => {
                return (
                  <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />
                );
              })}
              <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

2. Route.js

```js
import SignUp from "../components/SignUp";
import Home from "../components/Home";
     var routes = [
      {
        path: "/signup",
        name: "SignUp",
        component: SignUp,
      },
      {
        path: "/home",
        name: "HOME",
        component: Home,
      }
    }
    export default routes;
```

3. Follow this pattern, then you will not required write Router again and again

Comment: The OP's page structure is different than you are thinking. It has nested routes to navigate between...

Comment: Its just example. you can remove Login Page

Comment: For common Components like header footer, we create Layout File from there we try to write routing so that we can include common components like Header and footer

Comment: Thank you Amit, sorry about my comment before, my mistake. It is working well, but how is that working now ?

Comment: Didn't understand you in "we create Layout File from there we try to write routing so that we can include common components". Can you explain ? Still have issues with `Home` component not showing.

Comment: It's looping the inside `SignUp`'s  components

Answer (score 1):

You are having routes inside signup component and without router you cannot switch between routes. If you think it should work without router, then you are thinking that parent router should take the place but it's not correct because you are navigating components from the route which is not possible. Switching between routes it's only allowed when it is wrapped with router but not with router's route. The route component accepts the component but not routes itself.

Thus, to switch between routes inside the route, you must have a router.

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation Bhojendra. Is my way of navigation it is correct and advised?

Comment: It depends on the page structure how you want your user to navigate between. With your project requirement, it's absolutely fine.