# Componets are overlapping - showing one over the other - react router v5

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, protected

`SignUp` componentand `Home` component are overlapping . 
I have a protected route, the user will start in the `SignUp` page, when condition is true (`userSignedUp` is being updated at SignUp) it will transfer to the `Home`  component but the `SignUp` component is overlapping  and the one who's active (inputs and buttons).

Please check  -
**[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-liskov-2ny5y?file=/src/containers/App.js)** - the project.

(Here adding  `history.push('/home')` to `CreatePass` will end up with blank sigup component after exiting `Home`)

Anyone knows how to solve this issue, whats the problem with my code?

**App.js**

```js
 return (
    <div className='App-div'>
      <GuardedRoute path='/home' auth={userSignedUp}>
        <Home userIDNumber={userID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
      </GuardedRoute>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/signup'>
          <SignUp setUserNumber={setUserID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

**GuardedRoute.js**

```js
function GuardedRoute({ children, auth }) {
  return (
    <Route
      render={() => {
        return auth ? children : <Redirect to='/signup' />;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

##### Please try any of your solutions at my codesandbox before posting your answer

Comment: Hey! on going through your code it looks like you've used Route and GuardedRoute without a router, surround the code with a router(I would recommend HashRouter if it's your first time since other routers need help with routing during refreshing

Comment: @AdityaRastogi Sorry I don’t understand. Did you check my Index.js and SignUp.jsx ? They are both wrapped with Router. 
I don’t understand how to use the HashRouter and I read about it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving **path="/home"** to the GuardedRoute you will need to pass that to the Route inside the GuardedRoute

```
return (
    <div className='App-div'> 
     <Switch>
      <GuardedRoute path='/home' auth={userSignedUp}>
        <Home userIDNumber={userID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
      </GuardedRoute>
      {/* remove the exact here so so the route works when something is after the / */}
        <Route path='/signup'>
          <SignUp setUserNumber={setUserID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );


function GuardedRoute({ children, auth, path }) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={() => {
        return auth ? children : <Redirect to='/signup' />;
      }}
    />
  );
}

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.signUpProcess = this.signUpProcess.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      stage: 1,
    };
  }

 
  render() {
    return (
  <div className='signUp-div'>
    <Header />
        {/* remove the Router / */}
      <div className='form-div'>
        <Redirect to='/signup/mobile' />
        <Switch>
          <Route  path={'/signup/mobile'} component={MobileNum} />
          <Route  path={'/signup/idnumber'}>
            <IdentNumber setPersonalID={this.props.setUserNumber} />
          </Route>
          <Route  path={'/signup/password'}>
            <CreatePass
              setIfSignUp={this.props.setIfSignUp}
              pathsArray={pathArray}
            />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>

  </div>
);
```

}
}

in the CreatePass component

```
const handleClickButton = () => {
    if (passValue.length === 4 && confirmPass.length === 0) {
      textInput.current.focus();
    } else if (passValue === confirmPass && shouldUpdateMessage) {
      // booleanValue();
      //pathsArray.splice(0, pathsArray.length);
      //console.log(pathsArray);
      setIfSignUp(true);
      history.push('/home'); // uncomment this line
    }
  };
```

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing happens this way. Did you really tried it in my CodeSandbox ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-fast-9ncv4
Here is the working one i changed a few things i will add it in the anwser

Comment: Apparently you are wrong about this and check the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428256/why-child-component-should-be-wrapped-with-router-as-its-parent-component. It won't work without `Router` inside `Signup`.2) Pressing exit form `Home` in your codesanbox will transfer to an empty component with nothing but css. I wrote about that in my question. What exactly did you do in codesandbox ? I see no changes.

Comment: Works the same with `BrowserRouter` without `<Router history={history}>`, but must have in both SignUp.jsx and Index.js

Comment: Oke i had one file not saved sorry:
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-fast-9ncv4
Its works for me without the Router in the Signup.

Comment: So David Idk why but now it works without `<Router history={history}>` at `SignUp` component, and I still have overlapping components at `Home` as before. how did you solve this  ? and the transfer to `SignUp` from `Home` back again ?

Comment: Why did you added `Link`, and thank you for the effort to help me. I t doesnt work witout it

Comment: The Link was just to help me to go back to the signup so not needed.
i did edit my answer with each component i did change to make it work.
the overlap is that you need to pass the path to the Route in the GuardedRoute,
that Route does not have a path now. also you need to uncomment that  history.push('/home'); in the CreatePass component

Comment: Great solution, but now `Home` component is not protected and can go back to `SignUp` components... by pressing back button... and I'm back to my previous probelm David - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453594/protected-routes-for-react-router-v5-isnt-working   its frustrating me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235141/discussion-between-extrasun-and-david).